# What is the probability of selecting a random point q within x sq units of a random point p?

Tags: probability, surfaces

I was using an online app called "GeoGuessr" where you guess the location on a world map of a given Google Street view image. On one certain attempt, I picked a location within 92.7 square miles of the actual location.

I am intrigued by figuring out the statistical probability of guessing a random point that's within a given number of units squared. In this case, I am trying to find the probability of picking a point this close using random guessing.

The earth's total surface area, *A* is 196.9 million square miles.
I found a point *q* within 92.7 square miles of *p*.

I figure the probability of guessing that a random point is within 1 square mile of the actual location is 1:196900000. For a range up to 92.7, I divide 196,900,000 by 92.7 yielding ~ 1:2124056.

Is my arithmetic correct? If not, how should I solve the problem?

Comment: You're correct. Probablity in this case is $\frac{Favourable \space area}{Total \space area}$.

Comment: What does "...being within 92.7 square miles of the actual location" mean?

Comment: It means being within a circle with a radius of 92.7 miles across with a point (actual location) at the center of the circle.